# Archey showing wrong information

Tags: unity, command-line, 14.10

I noticed that when I type 'archey' in terminal it shows that I'm using Gnome DE, but clearly I'm using Unity. Why is that? Any ideas? Here's a picture about the problem. It's not a big thing, just bugs me. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[Source can be found here](https://github.com/djmelik/archey/blob/master/archey).

It does not support Unity:

```
deDict = {
'cinnamon-sessio': 'Cinnamon',
'gnome-session': 'GNOME',
'mate-session': 'MATE',
'ksmserver': 'KDE',
'xfce4-session': 'Xfce',
'lxsession': 'LXDE'
}
```

This command:

```
processes = str(subprocess.check_output(('ps', '-u', getuser(), '-o', 'comm',
'--no-headers')), encoding='utf8').rstrip('\n').split('\n')
```

evaluates to true for "gnome-session":

```
$ps -u {user} -o comm | grep gnome-session
gnome-session
```

What it should do is search for something with "unity" in it ...

```
$ps -u {user} -o comm | grep unity
unity-settings-
unity-panel-ser
unity-fallback-
unity-scope-hom
unity-scope-loa
unity-files-dae
unity-music-dae
```

---

Possible fix to the script on your machine:

```
deDict = {
'cinnamon-sessio': 'Cinnamon',
'gnome-session': 'GNOME',
'mate-session': 'MATE',
'ksmserver': 'KDE',
'xfce4-session': 'Xfce',
'lxsession': 'LXDE',
'unity-settings-': 'UNITY'
}
```

Oh and it should be reported [here](https://github.com/djmelik/archey/issues).

Comment: I copied that command to terminal, but it did nothing. It's possible that I did something wrong, but when it comes to terminal I'm a newbie. Can you tell me exactly what to do?

Comment: It is not a command. It is something you need to change in the script you start (ie. in "archey" with an editor).